# I want to align the text in a <td> to the top

Tags: html, css

I have the following code

```
<table style="height: 275px; width: 188px">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 259px;">
            main page
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The main page appears in the center of the cell I want it to appear at the top.

Answer (score 219, accepted):

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/vertical-align

```
<table style="height: 275px; width: 188px">
    <tr>
        <td style="width: 259px; vertical-align:top">
            main page
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

?

Answer (score 15):

Add a `vertical-align` property to the TD, like this:

```
<td style="width: 259px; vertical-align: top;">
main page
</td>
```

Answer (score 12):

Use `<td valign="top" style="width: 259px">` instead...

Comment: I don't agree which is why I asked. I see this as a styling thing therefore should be using a style attribute.

Comment: I think styling might be tricky in different browsers. Its not wrong, its a different way you can solve this issue. You know thisone is work too but I'll respect your opinion.

Comment: I was just wondering if you knew something I wasn't aware of, that's all

Comment: `<td valign="top" width="259">` was the valid solution before CSS.

Comment: For anyone reading this now, valign is not supported in html5 so it would be better to go with CSS instead.

Answer (score 12):

I was facing such a problem, look at the picture below

[image]

and here is its HTML

```
<tr class="li1">
    <td valign="top">1.</td>
    <td colspan="5" valign="top">
        <p>How to build e-book learning environment</p>
    </td>
</tr>
```

so I fix it by changing [valign Attribute](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_td_valign.asp) in both `td` tags to `baseline`

and it worked

here is the result [image]

hope this help you

Comment: This answer is a bad one. `valign` is not supported in HTML5 and should no longer be used. Use CSS's `vertical-align` or some other CSS fix.

Comment: valign is working for me. vertical-align is not.

Answer (score 4):

you can use `valign="top"` on the td tag it is working perfectly for me.

Comment: This answer is outdated now. Whoever is reading this, the `valign ` attribute is not supported anymore in html.